# For what SoapUI project XML schema need id?

Tags: xml, soapui

I want generate REST SoapUI project from json, but i have been confused by id in project XML, like `id="18ff3b79-b59e-4b88-a801-2c0efd3a09fc"`, so i need to know, for what SoapUI need those id and may i just delete all of them?

Comment: Looks like a UUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 0):

I believe that soapUI objects(test suites, test cases, test steps) can be accessed by id, index, and name.